# modules over principal ideal rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative principal ideal ring (not necessarily Artinian) and let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. Is $M$ a direct sum of cyclic $R$-modules? (i.e. a generalization of the theory of f.g. modules over a PID). I read somewhere that this is true, but I cannot find a reference where this is proven.

Comment: See the answer by Luc Guyot to the MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22722.

Comment: Direct link to this very answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/243540/14094

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: That answer is what I am looking for. I did a search after seeing it and also found the result spelled-out in theorem 15.33 in the book "Matrices over Commutative Rings" by William Brown